# Why my own Exception require no arguments?

Tags: java

I want to get VectorsDifferentSizeException when 1st and 2nd vector have different size.

But I'm getting "Constructor VectorsDifferentSizeException in class VectorsDifferentSizeException cannot be applied to given types"

required: no arguments
found: int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

```
public class Vectors {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Wektory x = new Wektory();
        x.getVector();      
    }
    
    void getVector() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] v1;
        double[] pom1 = new double[2];
        String[] splitted1; 
            
        double[] v2;
        double[] pom2 = new double[2];
        String[] splitted2;
        do {
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter first vector: ");
                String vec1 = input.nextLine();
                splitted1 = vec1.split(" ");
                v1 = new double[splitted1.length];
                for (int x=0; x<splitted1.length; x++) {
                    pom1 = checkType(splitted1[x]);
                    v1[x] = pom1[0];
                }           
            } while(pom1[1] == 1);          
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter second vector: ");
                String vec2 = input.nextLine();
                splitted2 = vec2.split(" ");
                v2 = new double[splitted2.length];
                for (int y=0; y<splitted2.length; y++) {
                    pom2 = checkType(splitted2[y]);
                    v2[y] = pom2[0];
                }
            } while(pom2[1] == 1);
            try {
                addVectors(v1, v2);
            }
            catch(VectorsDifferentSizeException e) {
                System.out.println("Vectors have different lengths!");
            }
        } while(v1.length != v2.length);    
            
        input.close();
    }
    
    double[] checkType(String c) {
        double[] a = new double[2];
        try {
            a[0] = Double.parseDouble(c);
            a[1] = 0;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Vector must be a number!");
            a[1] = 1;
        }
        return a;
    }
    
    void addVectors(double[] v1, double[] v2) throws VectorsDifferentSizeException {
        int vlen1 = v1.length;
        int vlen2 = v2.length;
        if (v1.length != v2.length) {
            throw new VectorsDifferentSizeException(vlen1, vlen2);
        }       
        double[] res = new double[v1.length];       
        for(int z=0; z<v1.length; z++) {
            res[z] = v1[z] + v2[z];
        }       
        try {
            PrintWriter save = new PrintWriter("result.txt");
            for(int i=0; i < v1.length; i++) {
                save.print(res[i]+" ");
            }                           
            save.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
    }
}

public class VectorsDifferentSizeException extends IOException {
    
    public void VectorsDifferentSizeException(int l1, int l2)   {
        System.out.println("The first length of the vector is " + l1 + " and second length is " + l2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void VectorsDifferentSizeException(int l1, int l2) ` is a method not a constrcutor

Comment: A constructor does NOT have a return type. So remove `void` from `public void VectorsDifferentSizeException(int l1, int l2)`

Comment: I removed `void` and it looks like this `public VectorsDifferentSizeException(int l1, int l2)` and I got now `invalid method declaration; return type required`

Comment: Dont you also need to provide a no arg constructor, and have your constructors call the super constructor.  Also, in my opinion, and it is just my opinion mind you, vectors being different sizes is more likely an `IllegalStateException` than an `IOException`, but than I do wonder if the vectors being different sizes are actually an exception in the first place.